# getting error r: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$total$ declare total integer;

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3dpbCYK7FeCMFcWRedBz17/2

I am trying to run my function using `postgresql database`.but I am getting this error

```
Schema Error: error: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$total$ declare total integer;"
Schema Error: error: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
Schema Error: error: syntax error at or near "RETURN"
Schema Error: error: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$total$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;"
Query Error: error: function totalrecords() does not exist
```

**can I check my function online ?**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT
);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (2);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalRecords ()  
RETURNS integer AS $total$  
declare  
    total integer;  
BEGIN  
   SELECT count(*) into total FROM test;  
   RETURN total;  
END;  
$total$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: dbfiddle simply does not support dollar quoting: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3dpbCYK7FeCMFcWRedBz17/2

Comment: Unrelated, but: simple functions like should be implemented as `language sql` functions

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  The link in your comment doesn't some useful.  I suspect you pasted the wrong link?

Comment: @jjanes: see this link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3dpbCYK7FeCMFcWRedBz17/4